# How do I get my directories/files on my Digital Ocean server, to my Bitbucket repo?

Tags: git, unix, bitbucket

I've tried numerous methods to try accomplish this so am just seeking a simple step-by-step on how to go about this. I have a Bitbucket repo at `https://user@bitbucket.org/user/project.git`. I have a Digital Ocean server with directories `env` (virtual env), `static` and `manage.py`. I want to *add* these files/directories to my Bitbucket repo - how do I do this?

I've tried:

1. `git remote add origin https://user@bitbucket.org/user/project.git`
2. `git add .`
3. `git commit -m "commit"`
4. `git push remote origin`

and had multiple errors throughout. At the moment, when I do `git add .` and then `git status`, it returns

```
On branch master
nothing to commit, working directory clean
```

If somebody could help me out here that would great.

Answer (score 0):

If you've already done steps #1-3 then you don't need to keep doing them - git knows about the remote, and you've already added and committed the content in whatever directory.

Your #4 here is a bit off, though. `git push` normally takes two arguments - the remote where you should push commits, and the branch you should push - though sometimes those are implicit. Try `git push origin master` - does that push your commits to Bitbucket?

Comment: I get this error when I do `git push origin master`:  `! [rejected]        master -> master (non-fast-forward)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://user@bitbucket.org/user/project.git'
hint: Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind
hint: its remote counterpart. Integrate the remote changes (e.g.
hint: 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.`

Comment: Yeah so I had a conflict with `.gitignore`: `CONFLICT (content): Merge conflict in .gitignore` so I did `git add .gitignore` then committed/pushed. But what happened after is it pushed to my bitbucket repo - however removed everything on the Bitbucket repo before...any idea why? How do I just *add* my server content to the Bitbucket repo?